# What does the error message "No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected." mean?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, uikit, provisioning

Yesterday I testet a lot on my device. Suddenly I get this error message when I hit Build & Go in Xcode. First, it asks me if it's ok to sign with my key. I click yes, and then that error message appears. My iPod is connected as usual, iTunes starts automatically and I close that to prevent interruptions.

I tried restarting Xcode. Doesn't help. My Apple Dev Enrollment is brand new. Any idea what the problem might be?

**Edit**: In Window > Organizer I can see this message:

> Your mobile device has encountered an
>   unexpected error (0xE8000001) Try
>   disconnecting and powering off the
>   device; then power the device on and
>   reconnect it.

I restarted it with power-off, but I still get that message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this happen before as well.  I'm not sure what caused it either, but in most instances powering the phone off and back on again solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

So, the final solution to that problem:

- Check if the provisioning profile is still in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
- If not, go download it from the iPhone Developer Program website
- Device power off (really off...you do that by holding that big standby button pressed for a few seconds)
- Quit Xcode (quit really: Check in Dock that it's not running)
- Activate device (power on), wait until it's bootet completely
- Plugin to your mac
- Wait until that harrying iTunes starts automatically, wait until it has synched your iPhone / iPod touch, and then switch iTunes off (really off).
- Start Xcode
- Build & Go
- Pray & have fun (hopefully)

Answer (score 2):

I was going to mention that dev certs eventually expire, until I saw you mention "My Apple Dev Enrollment is brand new."

Posting anyway in case it helps others... If your setup stops working out of the blue, you may have to download fresh certificates.

Comment: That's it, cert expired! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

if the ipod is brand new u have to check the (use for development) option in organiser