# getting the error" No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected" for iphone

Tags: iphone

what this error mean, when i am installing the app on device,i am getting this error.
how can i solve this error.

Comment: Have you generated a provisioning profile on the iPhone dev center, and loaded it onto your phone?

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841719/what-does-the-error-message-no-provisioned-iphone-os-device-is-connected-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device must be registered as an development device in your iPhone Developer Center. You also need to install the related profiles on your phone and the certificates on your machine. Take a look in your iPhone Developer Center, everything is explained in depth.

Answer (score 1):

log into the apple portal, go to the provisioning section for iPhone. Create development certificate for your mac, register your phone and then create a development profile. Install the profile and cert on your mac, and the provisioning profile on your phone.

While you are logged into the portal, there is some documentation you should take a look at that explains this a bit more fully - in fact there is a step-by-step wizard! If you are not a paid up developer (i.e. you have just registered and downloaded xcode and not paid Apple a fee) then on-device development and testing is not available to you.