# No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone 3G running iOS 4.2.1.

I have installed the correct provisioning profiles in the Xcode environment through the organizer tool. The iPhone device has also been checked and setup for development.

When I build my iPhone application, I am getting a message displaying that the "iPhone OS device connected is not provisioned".

I have Xcode 3.2.3 with the iPhone SDK 4.0 installed. Is this problem? Do I need to upgrade to Xcode 3.2.5 with iPhone SDK 4.2 to make this work?

Thanks for any advice.

Subbu

Comment: How about "[What does the error message “No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841719/what-does-the-error-message-no-provisioned-iphone-os-device-is-connected-mean)"?

Comment: I find provisioning problems are most easily debugging in x-code's organizer, check for problems there by selecting the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you won't be able to use the XCode distribution for iOS4.0 to provision to a device that is running iOS4.2. You'll want to upgrade your XCode distribution and then this should work just fine.